# Displaying code in blog posts

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

What libraries and/or packages have you used to create blog posts with code blocks? Having a JavaScript library that would support line numbers and  indentation is ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [GeSHi text highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is pretty awesome.  If you're using WordPress, [there's a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) for you already

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google query reveals http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

From initial looks it seems pretty good. Entirly JS based so can be implemented independent of the server side language used.

Comment: Yeah, Yahoo/Google search both gave good results. I'm asking more along the lines of what do you use and why.

Comment: Reading up on this one, performance doesn't look hot if you have a lot of code to display.

Answer (score 1):

[Syntax Highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) is used by [wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) and produces nice results.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Visual studio code as HTML http://www.jtleigh.com/people/colin/software/CopySourceAsHtml/

Answer (score 1):

I use Live Writer and I use VS addin that copies source code as html to copy the code and then I change into HTML view in Writer and paste the result

you can download the addin at:http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/11/21/copy-source-as-html-copysourceashtml-for-visual-studio-2008-rtm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I've done some research on this topic and came to the conclusion [that using GeSHi is the way to go](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2006/10/how-to-publish-good-looking-code-on.html). However recently I've been looking to some more alternatives:

- Using Windows Live Writer with a syntax highlighter plugin ([there](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=Highlight4Writer) [are](http://www.wilcob.com/Wilco/Toolbox/SyntaxHighlighter.aspx) [several](http://www.istaysharp.net/index.php?title=SyntaxColor4Writer) available)
- Using the [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) library or the [google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) library. Both are written in JS and I think the second one is used on stackoverflow
- Use some intermediate process, where I write the posts in Markdown for example and let a program generate the final HTML

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use this website to do it for me: http://puzzleware.net/codehtmler/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If that's my own code, I would just use [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)'s export to HTML and paste it.
Otherwise (highlighting code like it is done here), I would prefer to do it on server side: JS highlighting (as seen, for example, on JavaLobby) happens after the page have been displayed in default mode (so there is a sudden change of look, not very nice), and is often slow, plus JS can be disabled.
Actually, such task can be done once, after user input, it doesn't need to be done over and over on each page served to visitor.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [this free online tool that formats C# code](http://manoli.net/csharpformat/). Along with C#, it also formats code for VB, HTML, XML, T-SQL and MSH (code name Monad).